# detect series items of listbox vb6

Tags: algorithm, vb6

I want to detect series items of a listbox and move them to another listbox.
Suppose the list items are,

```
book01
book02
book03
book04
book05
apple
mango
pen
ball
packet1
packet2
packet3
```

There two series of `packet` and `book`. A timer will auto detect list1 series items and move to list2 book and packet series

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: This is a pretty rudimentary problem.  Iterate through list1 remove all items that start with "book" or "packet" and add them to list2.  What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

If I correct understand what you mean then this should do the job:

```
Private Sub MoveItems()
  Dim l As Long

  List2.Clear
  l = 0

  Do While l < List1.ListCount
    If InStr(List1.List(l), "packet") <> 0 Then
        MoveListItem l
    ElseIf InStr(List1.List(l), "book") <> 0 Then
        MoveListItem l
    Else
        l = l + 1
    End If
  Loop

End Sub

Private Sub MoveListItem(idx As Long)
  List2.AddItem List1.List(idx)
  List1.RemoveItem idx
End Sub
```